# How to refer to an entity using NDB by google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using gae-boilerplate (webapp2 and jinja2). My model looks like this:

```
class Location(ndb.Model):
    x = ndb.FloatProperty()
    y = ndb.FloatProperty()

class Criterium(polymodel.PolyModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User')
    priority = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)

class Work(Criterium):
    location = ndb.StructuredProperty(Location)

class Friend(Criterium):
    location = ndb.StructuredProperty(Location)
```

I have a table with all records from the Criterium model. I would like to add a delete link there, but I don't know what argument to pass with it in order to refer to the specific entity. My handler looks like this:

```
def get(self):
    criteria = Work.query().order(-Criterium.priority, Criterium.name)
    self.view.list_columns = [('name', 'Name'),
                         ('priority', 'Priority'),
                         ('className', 'Type')]
    self.view.criteria = criteria
    self.view.count = criteria.count()
    params={}
    self.render_template('list.html', **params)
```

Seems like a simple problem, but have been struggling all day... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Singular of criteria is 'criterion', not 'criterium'.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I didn't like the word criterium.

Answer (score 1):

what about the `id` of the object?
thats the unique identifier for that object within the `Criterium` model.

when looping over the criteria entities:

```
for criterum in criteria:
    criterum.key.id()
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working.

I now use this in my html:

    <a class="icon" href="{{ uri_for('work-delete', id=criterium.key.id())}}"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>

Is this safe?

Comment: Not sure how safe it is but that is how i delete line items

Comment: I guess it would be better to pass the key back to work-delete ?

Comment: if we speak about safety i am really confident to say that sending an `id` around is way safer than a complete key which contains a lot of info about your app and data structure. i would not be concerned to show the actual id of an entity.

Comment: @peterretief what makes you think using a key is safer than an id? would you rather send all your creditcard data somewhere or an identifier to retrieve and recontstruct the data somewhere else?

Comment: @aschmid00 the only thing about sequential id's is that its easy to guess the sequence and surely the key is only useful in context?

Comment: the ids are not sequential. at least mine aren't.

Answer (score 0):

see example below

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class User(ndb.Model):

```
created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
firstName = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
lastName = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
email = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
pwHash = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)

@classmethod
def byEmail(cls, email):
    u = cls.query(cls.email == email).get()
    return u

@classmethod
def register(cls, firstname, lastname, email, password):
    pwhash = utils.makePwHash(email, password)
    return User(firstName=firstname,
        lastName=lastname,
        email=email,
        pwHash=pwhash)

@classmethod
def login(cls, email, password):
    u = User.byEmail(email)
    if u and utils.validPW(email, password, u.pwHash):
        return u
```